# Bootstrap hidden.bs.dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am stylizing Bootstrap dropdowns, and I am making the list items slide in as the dropdown appears.
http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/ffwvv347/

```
// Smooth Dropdown transition
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    var listItems = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").find("li a");
    listItems.animate({opacity : '1', left : '0px'}, 400, 'linear');

});



$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
$(".dropdown").on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function(){
    var listItems = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").find("li a");
    listItems.css({'opacity' : '0', 'left' : '-50px'});
});
```

What it is supposed to do is animate the left position of the list items as they slide down, making a cool animation. However, when the list slides back up, the items vanish immediately, instead of waiting until the dropdown is completely hidden, as the `hidden.bs.dropdown`is meant to work. Why is it hiding before the dropdown is completely hidden, and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

use the same animate to hide and set slide upand and down time equals to animate time, but it's up to you.

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
    var listItems = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").find("li a");
    listItems.animate({opacity : '0', left : '-50px'}, 400, 'linear');
});
```